# Python psycopg2 DELETE data in AWS, no result, no error

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, amazon-web-services

I try to delete data in a table in AWS. The code below works well if I pull data from AWS.

```
import psycopg2
import pandas as pd

con=psycopg2.connect(dbname= My_Credential.....)
cur = con.cursor()

sql = """
DELETE FROM my_table
"""

cur.execute(sql)
```

After runing the code, I don't have any error message, but if I go check the data in that table, the data is still there. I wonder if I need to add any code like to COMMIT the change?

please advise. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out. I need to add

```
con.commit()
```

to make it work